# Firestore (6.2.0) Internal Unhandled Error

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use firestore in my react-native app, but when I add firebase.firestore().collection() I got this error

None of the solutions that i found searching works for me

My class:

```
import firebase from '../backend/Connection2';

componentDidMount(){
  this.test();
}

test(){
  firebase.firestore().collection('pause').doc('pause').set({
    name: 'San Francisco', state: 'CA', country: 'USA',
    capital: false, population: 860000
  });
}
```

Connection2:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import firestore from 'firebase/firestore'

const settings = {};

const config = {
  apiKey: "lorem ipsum",
  authDomain: "lorem ipsum",
  databaseURL: "lorem ipsum",
  projectId: "lorem ipsum",
  storageBucket: "lorem ipsum",
  messagingSenderId: "lorem ipsum",
  appId: "lorem ipsum"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.firestore().settings(settings);

export default firebase;
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "jdp_android",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/app": "^0.4.5",
    "@firebase/app-types": "^0.4.0",
    "@firebase/firestore": "^1.4.0",
    "@firebase/messaging": "^0.3.22",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^3.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^0.0.4",
    "firebase": "^6.0.4",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.25",
    "opencollective-postinstall": "^2.0.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-stopwatch-timer": "^0.0.20",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvVlL.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khXmn.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcT7j.jpg)

Comment: Copy and paste the error here, not just screenshot

Comment: [Downgrading to 6.0.2 fixes the issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1824)